# Sparx Enterprise Architect Oracle XE repository: increasing column width above 50 chars

Tags: database, oracle, repository, enterprise-architect

we are using Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA 9.2) and a database-backed repository (Oracle XE 11, using Windows OLE / ODBC driver). All of us are working on Windows Vista 32bit.

We are repeatedly running into the following EA error when importing models:

```
OraOLEDB
ORA-12899: value too large for column "REPOUSER"."T_CONNECTOR"."BTM_MID_LABEL" 
  (actual: 52, maximum: 50)
```

It appears that some columns have been created with a width of only 50 characters. I would like to increase this size. Therefore, the questions are:

1. does EA 9.2 support wider columns? has anybody successfully tried this out for real projects?
2. if "yes": how would EA 9.2 react to a DB-side increase of the values? would I need to re-create the connection?
3. if the answer to both questions is "yes": has anyone any experiences with "broadening" the columns of Oracle XE 11 *at runtime*, without dumping-and-reimporting into a new schema?

Many thanks,

MiKu

Answer (score 1):

This error on import occurs only in Oracle, probably because of the way Oracle handles extended character ranges.

There are three other options you have to work around it:
1. If the connector in question is a Stateflow then run Enterprise Architect's Project Data Integrity check: Project -> Data Management -> Project Integrity Check

2. If it is not a StateFlow then you could try set the option on Oracle NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS ='CHAR'; However I would test this on a non production database first!!
3. If you clean out the TOP_MID_LABEL fields in the database, when Enterprise Architect loads the diagram again it will dynamically fill it with the element name (if the field is empty).

I believe the developers at Sparx Systems have a cleaner way of handling this in the works, so knowing them, something might be available in the very near future.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the Oracle part of yopur question, widening the columns is easy.  Oracle allows us to increase column sizes even if they comntain data.  (This is not true if we want to decrease the column sizes: then we must work with empty columns and re-populate the data.)

So the syntax is:

```
 alter table REPOUSER.T_CONNECTOR modify BTM_MID_LABEL varchar2(60) ;
```

... or whatever value you think will be large enough.